# Passing Variables in PHP Switch Function

Tags: php, wordpress, switch-statement

I am having some issues passing variables into a switch function.

It's a wordpress site so right now I have:

```
    $_slider_plus_length = '1';
    $_slider_plus_max_height = '350';
    $_slider_plus_max_width = '1000';


function switchIt() {
    $_slider_plus_length = '1';
    $_slider_plus_max_height = '350';
    $_slider_plus_max_width = '1000';

    switch ($_slider_plus_length) {
        case '1':
            return '<li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_one' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li>';
            break;
        case '2':
            return '<li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_one' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li><li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_two' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li>';
            break;
        case '3':
            return '<li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_one' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li><li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_two' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li><li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_three' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li>';
            break;
        case '4':
            return '<li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_one' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li><li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_two' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li><li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_three' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li><li><img src="'. get_option( 'slider_plus_image_four' ) .'"style="height:'. $_slider_plus_max_height .'px;max-width:'. $_slider_plus_max_width .'px;"></li>';
            break;
        default:
            return $_slider_plus_list_item_one;
    }

}
```

I need these variables in the switch function but I don't really want to redeclare them like this.

I tried to set them as global but I couldn't get it!

I know its some basic stuff that I am missing... teaching myself things, think I skipped some steps.

Thanks,
Matt